# 'lessc' is not recognized as an internal or external command (Django, Apache) on Windows 7

Tags: django, windows, apache, less

I'm trying to deploy Django project using Apache and having some problems. I use nodejs's less compiler in conjunction with django-static-precompiler and everything works fine on the dev server. However, when I try to use Apache, I get the following error "'lessc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Thing is, lessc command is available globally in the console and I cannot understand why this command becomes unknown when I use Apache.

I use Python 3.4.2, Apache 2.4.10.

Here's config from Apache:

```
WSGIPythonHome C:\Python34
WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi "D:\PythonProjects\VSDjangoTest\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1\wsgi.py"
<Directory "D:\PythonProjects\VSDjangoTest\DjangoWebProject1\DjangoWebProject1">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order deny,allow
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Here's wsgi.py

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('D:/PythonProjects/VSDjangoTest')

sys.path.append('D:/PythonProjects/VSDjangoTest/DjangoWebProject1')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "DjangoWebProject1.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Does Apache use other environment variables? Can anyone clarify this please?

UPDATE:
If I set path to lessc explicitly, everything works fine:

```
LESS_EXECUTABLE = 'C:/Users/Ilya/AppData/Roaming/npm/lessc'
```